# Geometry nodes: control light intensity

Tags: lighting, geometry-nodes

I'd like to create a geometry node that automatically adds a light and configure its intensity based on the inputs of the nodes. I managed to add the light using an additional collection + the `object info` node:

[image]

However I can't find how to play with the intensity of the light. Note that ideally I would like to use the point light, and I would like to avoid tricks like putting the light further and further because then it would interfere with other parts of the scene.